# Can I ask about installing mods?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

I'm asking this question because I dont want the other question to be put on hold, is asking a question about how to install world edit on minecraft worthy of being put on hold?

Comment: @soulreaper You might want to read [this page](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)!

Comment: Unless the home page for WorldEdit has a clearly marked "How to" guide for installing it, I would say it's a reasonable question...if it does though, you should probably just follow the directions given unless you run into some difficulties doing so, then explicitly state the problem you ran into while installing it.  A good rule of thumb is to try to solve the problem first, to find an answer second, and to then ask a question about it third.

Comment: @Zibbobz WorldEdit does have a clear set of instructions in its downloads section on [how to install it](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit). (It refers readers to the install instructions of SinglePlayer Commands, which is a necessary mod to use WE.) It's easy for the impatient to miss, yes, but "I didn't read what I was supposed to" isn't really our fault.

Answer (score 5):

It would depend on the question itself.  From the short description you've given us, it sounds like it would be on topic.  It would be a [duplicate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128502/how-do-i-install-worldedit-for-minecraft-1-6-2) of [something already asked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122246/how-to-install-mods-for-the-new-minecraft-1-6-1-launcher), though.

Be aware that if that's *all* your question is, you're going to get lots of downvotes for showing no effort.

Comment: As you type a question's name, it will (usually) bring up a list of questions like it that will indicate whether it has been asked before (Or something similar), and it pays to check and see if your question is fully answered by these questions.  If not, it pays to reword the question to cover anything that wasn't covered.

Comment: Well i don't know how to show effort.

Comment: Like they say in school, "Show your work".  Did you do anything to try to figure this out before asking here?  Did you try following directions, and got stuck somewhere along the line?  While showing effort isn't a requirement for asking a question, it's usually looked upon as something nice to do, so that we don't have to waste time repeating the stuff you've already done.

Comment: @soulreaper It's never too late to learn. Reading old questions is a good way to get started.

Comment: @soulreaper showing effort is like, ""I've found a site (you would need to link it there) and Have found the download, however it says I need to use Minecraft Forge which I have from another site, How do I know which minecraft forge do I have? I looked in my Minecraft launcher and all it says is Forge in a profile, The forge file I have is just called forge.java located in C:\Users\SupaBeast\AppData\.minecraft\mods\MineCraft Forge\"" It shows that you've tried, where you've been and how to better assist you.